# Consider a function $g: (-1, +1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, continuity, inverse

Consider a function $g: (-1, +1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$g(x) = \frac{x}{1-|x|}$

Show that $g$ is 1-1 and find $g((-1,1))$

Find $g^{-1}$

Are $g$ and $g^-1$ continuous

---

I found that $g$ is 1-1 by contradiction. I assumed that $g(x_0)=g(x_1)$ where $x_0 \not= x_1$. I showed through trichotomy (moving the zero around) that it is impossible for the first condition to hold if the latter is true.

To find $g((-1,1))$ do I take limits?  If not, any hints?

For part II, How does one take the inverse of an absolute value? I'd imagine that it is not continuous.

Obviously, without an answer to part II, I cannot have a justified answer for the final part.

Comment: Limits is fine: $\;g(x)\xrightarrow[x\to -1^+]{}-\infty\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first observe that $y = g(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-|x|}$ is odd. we only need to worry about $x \ge 0.$  in this domain $y = \dfrac{x}{1-x} = -1+\dfrac{1}{1-x}.$ that is $g$ is increasing on $[0, 1)$ and has a vertical asymptote at $x = 1.$

you can find the inverse by solving for $y = -1 + \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ which gives $x = 1 - \dfrac{1}{1+y} = \dfrac{y}{1+y}$

therefore $g^{-1}(x) =\dfrac{x}{1+x} \text{ for }x\ge 0.$ you can extend it as an odd function to get $$g^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{x}{1+|x|}.  $$

Comment: I do not understand the first two sentences. Why does the function being off mean we are only concerned with the domain $x \geq 0$? Are you saying that any argument used for that domain can be used in a parallel form to prove the rest of the domain?

Comment: @BobtheBuilds, a function like $f(x) = x^3$ is odd because $f(2) = -8$ and $f(2) = 8$ that is $f(-x) = -f(x).$ for odd functions, knowing the function values for $x ge 0$ is enough. in terms of the graph, you reflect on both $x$ and $y$ axis of the graph $\{(x, f(x): x \ge 0\}.$

Answer (score 0):

$\;g\;$ is clearly continuous on $\;(-1\,,\,1)\;$ as a quotient of continuous functions here without the denominator's function vanishing in the domain.

For the inverse function:

$$y=\frac x{1-|x|}\implies y-y|x|-x=0=\begin{cases}y-(y+1)x=0\implies x=\frac y{1+y}&,\;0\le x\\{}\\y+(y-1)x=0\implies x=\frac y{1-y}&,\;x<0\end{cases}$$

So we get that

$$g^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac x{1+x}&,\;\;0\le x\\{}\\\frac x{1-x}&,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

So...is the inverse continuous?

Comment: @strants Following the end of my first lines, we get $\;x=\frac y{1+y}\;$ for $\;x\ge 0\;$ , and this gives *in this case* the inverse function, which is what's written in the lower line. It is exactly what is written in abel's answer.

Comment: My mistake, I must have misread.  I guess I expected $x\ge0$ and $x<0$ to be the cases (as opposed to $x\ge0$ and $0>x$, as you wrote them).

Answer (score 0):

To find the inverse function divide the given function in two parts:
$$
y=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x}{1-x} \quad  0\le x<1\\
\dfrac{x}{1+x} \quad  -1< x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
then invert each part being careful to the domain of $y$.